# How to schedule multiple Azure WebJobs to avoid high memory and cpu utilization?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I am trying to deploy WebJobs on Azure, in such a way it should not collide at same time .

I have 3 types jobs.

1. Job1 runs continuously / indefinitely
2. Job2 runs every 30 minutes and it takes 8 minutes to complete
3. Job3 runs every 60 minutes and it takes 12-15 minutes to complete.

How we can schedule Job2 or Job3 so cycle doesn't overlap or coincide at same time.

Performance thought : Job2 and Job3 both require high memory and cpu utilization, if both start at same time our AppService crashed.

Comment: What do you want to happen when it is overlapping, postpone until the other job is done or until the next 'tick'?

Comment: Yes @Peter Bons

Comment: Yes what? 1) wait until other one is finished, 2) wait until next 'tick' :-)

Comment: what to do for - wait until other one is finished ? @PeterBons